# Using hidden WebView and calling out functions between Javascript and Java code

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to create an Android App but I'm not too familiar with Java. I was thinking to use a hidden WebView to store my core code (as Javascript) there and call out functions between WebView's Javascript and app's Java code. Is this a bad practice? I know that I can use frameworks like Cordova, PhoneGap but they are all bloated with code that I will never use.

Answer (score 0):

3 Reasons to Prefer React Native,

1. 1- You are good at JavaScript (you told that you are not too
   familiar with Java)
2. React Native is Really Native
3. JSX and
   React Component Props (eg. flex styles almost same with CSS) are
   close to JavaScript Developers

WebView is not the best practice ;)

Good Luck